# Program Writes to /opt/.../logs - Need a Way to write to /home/<user>/<program>/logs - Linux

Tags: linux, logging

I work for a small software company.  We have a product that by default writes to a logs directory inside the installation directory (I know, this may not be the best way, but it's fixed as of now): `/opt/<program>/logs`

I have a user that wants each of his users (on Linux) when running our program, to have logs written to their user directory per session, like `/home/<user>/<program>/logs`.  Is there a good way to set this up, relying on my program always writing to `/opt/<program>/logs` by default?

I'm no Linux expert but I'm thinking this could be done.

Would this be better asked on the Linux SE board?

Any help is appreciated!

**NOTE** - These logs are created for the program when it runs, no matter who is logged in to use it.  They all go to the same directory: `/opt/<program>/logs`.  If I create a symlink, then all that does it duplicate the logs into another directory.  What I need is each user's logs for their session into their respective `/home/<user>/<program>/logs` directory.

Answer (score 3):

Create a link from the `/opt/program/logs` folder and point it to `/home/user/logs`:

```
ln -s /home/user/logs /opt/program/logs
```

Comment: See note above - not sure this get's me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the /logs/ directory, and navigating to /opt/program and typing

ln -s ~/logs

However, you will need to add a

mkdir ~/logs

to each users startup script.

Answer (score 1):

How does the log look like? Is there a possibility to check which user created an entry?
You could use the `syslog-ng` to watch for the files in `/opt/<program>/logs` and depending on the entry (e.g. a regular expression) writing a second logfile to `$USERHOME/logs`.

If just one user is using your program you may give him read-permissions to this directory and its files. But if there are sensible entries from other users  this is a bad idea.

Comment: No way to see which user created the entry, as the logs are somewhat non-specific.  Multiple users will be using this program, hence the need for separate logs...  Thanks!  I wonder if you could parse based on time, and connect that to the user login time...